# Why MetalLB cannot provide a real load balancing feature in layer 2 mode?

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, arp

The [documentation of MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/concepts/layer2/) states that:

> In layer 2 mode, all traffic for a service IP goes to one node.

To my understanding, this is mostly due to the fact that:

> one node assumes the responsibility of advertising a service to the local network.

As mentioned in the rest of the said documentation, this behavior implies a severe limitation. The traffic bandwidth is limited to what can pass through the elected node. But is it due to ARP as it is claimed in the documentation?

A solution I could imagine to remove this limitation is to have one "speaker" per node. When a new set of pod and service is deployed, the speaker running on the node which runs the new node is in charge of the ARP announcement. This way, the inbound traffic always takes the optimal route. Is it technically doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MetalLB is correct. Playing level 2 addressing games means that only one host can receive unicast traffic at once. Per service address.

Say `2001:db8:c0ba:4816::a` is the service address and is currently pointing to a NIC at Ethernet `6E:17:C2:2E:F4:A4`. A failure in that host triggers a failover. Some neighbor discovery happens and now it points to a different host with `6E:17:C2:2E:E7:B8`. There is no opportunity to multi path, the HA protocol and the unicast workload are too simple for that. Sure could have more service addresses, so add `2001:db8:c0ba:4816::b` which could go to another, possibly unused, host.

Active/passive setup like this will be familiar to users of VRRP or PowerHA clusters. Except MetalLB reimplemented their own thing for some reason.

MetalLB BGP mode is different, layer 3 routing. Which makes ECMP possible if multiple next hops are installed for the service address route. Compare to designs for [large multiple tier load balancers using ECMP](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2018-multi-tier-loadbalancer).

One active host per service IP may not be a problem, depending on design. Hosts can scale up quite large, perhaps with 25 Gb links. If necessary, doing real work could be moved to other hosts, leaving just a proxy to terminate front end connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `add 2001:db8:c0ba:4816::b which could go to another [...] host.` That's exactly what I mean. LoadBalancing a single Service is indeed not possible as it has a single IP, but we could assigning the IP address to different physical machines. Thanks for confirming!